# chrome store item update frequency

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Sorry for my noob question, but somebody knows how much time it take for an item to update at the chrome store (item rating for example) ?

I just published my first chrome extension yesterday and yet the item hasn't updated.

Couldn't find the answer myself, but I think the duration is not constant.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: seems like it takes 4 days.

Comment: There is no definite time. Try this [How to Manually Update Your Chrome Extensions](http://lifehacker.com/5805239/how-to-manually-update-your-chrome-extensions) guide.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I'm looking for other kind of update- not update the version of the extension but update the extension status in the chrome store.